# How to write a storedprocedure using mySQL which updates x number of records only?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to write a stored procedure in MySQL which fetches the accounts using where condition, 
divides it by 10 and updates the number of the rows based on the result.

For an example, if the total accounts is 100, I would put a lock on 100/10 = 10 records and updates them.

I am newBee to this. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice to make tow step process.

```
     select @rowcount := count(1) from account;
```

Then use `LIMIT` to set the limit on rows to be updated:

```
     UPDATE account
     SET column1 = desiredvalue
     LIMIT @rowcount/10;
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

```
     select @rowcount := ROUND(count(1)/10) from account;
     UPDATE account
     SET column1 = desiredvalue
     LIMIT @rowcount;
```

or

```
     DECLARE rowcount INTEGER;
     SELECT ROUND(count(1)/10) INTO rowcount from account; 
     UPDATE account
     SET column1 = desiredvalue
     LIMIT rowcount;
```

Comment: Hi Yogendra, Thanks for the help.How to assign a value to a variable in mySQL. I mean how can i assign the total number of count to rowCount as mentioned in above exmaple using mySql. var rowcount <- select count(1) from account (psuedo statement) is giving error.

Comment: @Gendaful: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks Yogendra, but it gives error at LIMIT @rowcount/10; I have used the query as select @rowcount := count(*) from account;UPDATE account
     SET column1 = desiredvalue
     LIMIT @rowcount/10;

Comment: @Gendaful: What error are you getting? I added another version. Can you please try that?

Comment: I am getting SQL Error 1064: It is at line where I am specifying the limit @rowcount/10. It is not taking @rowcount at all :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18673/discussion-between-gendaful-and-yogendra-singh)

Comment: @Gendaful: Did you try the other query from my updated answer as well?